# Disable and enable a tag on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can we disable `a` tag  and enable it after adding class ?
something like this :

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass('ajax-link').attr('rel', '#content')
  $(this).animate({
    'top': '100px',
  })
  // want to re-enable it and do the normal behaviour
  $(this).trigger('click')
  return true
})
```

Comment: So do you want to click on the anchor tag and add a class to disable it and then reenable it (all in the one click)? Or do you want to click it and then disable it, and then click it again to then reenable it?

Comment: you can remove href with : `javascript:;`

Comment: What's the problem with your own code?

Comment: when user click on a tag, at first i don't want to redirect it to another page.
i want to stop this and add class after that back the a tag to normal behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way :

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  $(this).addClass('ajax-link')

  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')
})
```

```css
.ajax-link {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<a href="https://google.com">Test</a>
```

You basically prevent the default action of the anchor that way the click won't work, then you add the class and manually send the user to the link.

I am sure that there are many other ways to do what you asked, this is just one of them that is simple and intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can add css property `pointer-events: none;` like below.`

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
//alert();
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass('disabled');  
  
  // window.location.href = $(this).attr('href')
  });
```

```css
a.disabled {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
    color:#D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
   <a href="https://www.google.com/" >Hello My Click</a>   
</div>
```

`